# Excel VBA if formula value in cell is less than zero then msgbox

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, vba

Im trying to get a msgbox when the value in the cell which is updated with a formula is less than zero.

For example:

a1= 5

b5= a1

if b5 is less than zero then msgbox "your value is less than zero"

Hope someone can help me

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Include the following **event** macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If [B5] < 0 Then
        MsgBox "your value is less than zero"
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**